# Prove that $\vec{v}$ is also an eigenvector for $A^{k}$(k = a positive integer). What is the corresponding eigenvalue?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Prove that $\vec{v}$ is also an eigenvector for $A^{k}$(k = a positive integer). What is the corresponding eigenvalue?

What I have started with is, $A=(CDC^{-1})$ which can be used to prove

$A^{2}=(CDC^{-1})(CDC^{-1})
=C(DC^{-1}C)DC^{-1}
=CD^{2}C^{-1}$

Thus, $A^{k}=CD^{k}C^{-1}$ I think this will help me find my proof, but I am not sure.

Comment: +1 for your avatar. I know it. It is Neverhood, an old game.

Comment: yeah good job! most people don't remember that series anymore, probably the best (of very few) claymation games. great soundtrack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try looking at $A^{k-1}(Av)$. Do this process inductively.

Comment: There is a follow up problem to find the corresponding eigenvalue if $\lambda $ = -5 for $A^{3}$. Am I correct that the answer would be $-125\vec{v}$?

Comment: Try it out! $A^3v=A^2(Av)=-5A^2v=-5A(Av)...$

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* If $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$ then 
$$
A v = \lambda v \implies A^2 v = A(Av) = A(\lambda v) = \lambda (Av) = \lambda (\lambda v) = \lambda ^2 v \implies \cdots
$$